# a rotation matrix composed of vectors needs to be normalized or not?

Tags: graphics, shader, gpu

Recently I saw little code snippet somewhere in one's shader.

the code as following( it really doesn't matter what shader language is. )

```
float2 mv = tex2Dlod(_CameraMotionVectorsTexture, uv).rg * _Amplitude;

// Make a rotation matrix based on the motion vector.
float2x2 rot = float2x2(mv.y, mv.x, -mv.x, mv.y);

// Rotate and scale the body of the arrow.
float2 pos = mul(rot, v.vertex.zy) * _Scale.xy;

// Normalized variant of the motion vector and the rotation matrix.
float2 mv_n = normalize(mv);
float2x2 rot_n = float2x2(mv_n.y, mv_n.x, -mv_n.x, mv_n.y);

// Rotate and scale the head of the arrow.
float2 head = float2(v.vertex.x, -abs(v.vertex.x)) * 0.3;
head *= saturate(color.a);
pos += mul(rot_n, head) * _Scale.xy;
```

as your guy see, that rot matrix was made of motion vector which do not normalize. but the two axis vector of the second rotation matrix called `rot_n` get normalized instead, that just normalized on the motion vector before create the rotation matrix. i can't figure out why, why can not the author of the code normalize the motion vector all the way before make the rotation matrix?

could somebody help me get rid of the question, i really appreciate it. thank you in advanced!

Comment: `rot` is not a pure rotation matrix. It may include a scaling. This is probably done to account for the extent of the arrow, whereas the head should not be scaled based on the arrow's length. But it's impossible to tell without knowing the input.

Comment: @Nico Schertler 。  hi, you re right,just cancel scale linear transform out if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be scale involved in，just undo scale on it.is it?